# Encrypt Password

Tags: javascript

I have a login page having username and password after successful entry of username and password, it forward to the login controller.
My problem is that while forwarding to next page, in url the password enter is showing. I need to encrypt that and send over controller and have to decrypt that over controller.

this is my code.

jsp:

```
 <form action="Login" onsubmit="return validate1()">
                <h3>
                    <font color="red">username</font>
                </h3>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br>

                <h3>
                    <font color="red">password</font>
                </h3>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br> <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    function validate1() {
        return validate();
    }
    function validate() {
        var isValid = true;
        var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        if (name.length == 0) {
            isValid = false;
            alert("Username empty");
        } else if (password.length == 0) {
            isValid = false;
            alert("Password empty");
        }
        return isValid;
    }
</script>
```

url:
    http://localhost:8080/PSMS/Login?username=jay&password=jay

here password is visible I need to encrypt the password and forward to controller where again I have to decrypt that password.

Comment: One option is you can make it as post method, so it won't get displayed in URL.

Comment: Also you should use https.

Comment: in `form` use `method=Post` and it wont show in URL

Comment: You should use post method. so in form tag use `method="POST"`.

Comment: Also using encryption in javascript in the browser isn't really safe as anyone with access to the page could gain the encryption keys/algo and therefore decrypt the passwords

Comment: thank guys it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need add an attribute to your form tag.

```
<form method="post"> ...
```